# MySQL stored Procedure error with IF...THEN...END IF; statements

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, if-statement, syntax-error

I have a MySQL stored procedure that throws an error.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test_schema`.`TEST_SPROC` $$  
CREATE PROCEDURE `test_schema`.`TEST_SPROC` (IN var0 INT, var1 INT)  
BEGIN

  DECLARE var0 INT;
  DECLARE var1 INT;

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO var0 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.`TABLES` 
  WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='test_schema' AND `TABLE_NAME`='original_table'; 

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO var1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.`COLUMNS` 
  WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='test_schema' AND `TABLE_NAME`='new_table' 
  AND `COLUMN_NAME`='id';

  IF var0=1 THEN
    RENAME TABLE test_schema.original_table TO test_schema.new_table;   
  END IF;

  IF var1=1 THEN
    ALTER TABLE test_schema.new_table CHANGE id AccountID VARCHAR;   

  END IF;       #error is thrown here.

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Error:

> Script line: 4    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ';   END IF;
>
> END' at line 15

What is wrong with my if statement?

Comment: Your if statement is correctly formed.  It's the alter table statement that has syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
ALTER TABLE test_schema.new_table CHANGE id AccountID VARCHAR;
```

to this:

```
ALTER TABLE test_schema.new_table CHANGE id AccountID VARCHAR(100);
```

Of course you should specify a length for the `VARCHAR` column that is appropriate. I've just used `VARCHAR(100)` as an example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a length for the alter table statement.  See the comment below:

```
IF varTable=1 THEN
    RENAME TABLE test_schema.original_table TO test_schema.new_table;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO varColumn FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.`COLUMNS` 
    WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='test_schema' AND `TABLE_NAME`='new_table' 
    AND `COLUMN_NAME`='id';

    IF varColumn=1 THEN
      #The following statement must be "VARCHAR(255)"  not just "VARCHAR"
      ALTER TABLE test_schema.new_table CHANGE id AccountID VARCHAR(255);
    ELSE
      #statements.
    END IF;
END IF;
```